# Is Nokogiri platform specific?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, package, nokogiri

I am using windows 7.
I have installed nokogiri gem and checked out the gem specification.

In the gemfile, it says nokogiri is platform specific. 
 s.platform = "x86-mingw32"

Does it mean that nokogiri can be installed only on windows?

Or Am I just getting line in the gemspec just because I am using windows 7??

Or Nokogiri builds upon libxml2-2.8.0, libxslt-1.1.28, zlib-1.2.8, libiconv-1.14.

Can we install nokogiri on other platforms as long as libxml, libxslt, zlib, libiconv??

Comment: This isn't a SO question.  Nokogiri is a gem with dependencies, it's an unreasonable request for us to figure out all the permutations of environments people might set up with Nokogiri and then to safeguard against those that **might** not work.

Comment: I am not asking people to list out all the environments here. I am asking if I am getting that s.platform = x86-mingw32 because I am using windows. I was wondering what other people would get x86-mingw32 in the gemsepc if they use other platforms.

Comment: @Anthony The information provided shows that the nokogiri gem was compiled for Windows so that compiled version indeed will only run on Windows.  It is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Nokogiri Requires C Extensions

"x86-mingw32" means that your Nokogiri C extensions were compiled with the [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) compiler suite. It's conceivable that you could force compilation on win32 with another compiler, but other platforms (e.g. Linux or OS X) will certainly require GCC, LLVM, or something else.

So, compiler needs will vary by platform. Likewise, some Ruby *interpreters* may or may not allow you build certain C extensions, especially on alternate platforms. Your mileage can vary a lot in this regard.